# Power query - turning number strings into numbers while preserving text

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have a set of data:

1
2
3
Infinity
4
5

The numbers are registered as strings inside of power query for some reason.

I'd like to convert the numbers to the percentage type (Or any other type really, depending on my needs), while preserving any text present.

I wish that I wasn't given mixed string-data columns (And the source of the string in the first place is replacing a div0! error), but we all work with what we have >_<

I've tried using the type converter inside of power query, but it overwrites the text with a null.

(Interestingly, since the text is "Infinity", it displays the infinity symbol inside of the power query window... it just doesn't load the symbol)

Answer (score 0):

I would use **Duplicate Column** (from the Add Column ribbon) to make a copy of the column so you can preserve it as entered.  Then I would Change the duplicated column's data type to Percentage.  That way you can meet all requirements.

Comment: While it technically meets the requirements, it's not very useable for the end-users - one column has %, the other has the % as unreadable numbers and strings.

Comment: I'd be keen to learn about alternatives that would be more useable.

Comment: Yeah, my 'solution' will be extremely unsatisfying to anyone finding this question - I convinced the powers that be to let it default into a null, then have a calculated column flag indicate it. Fairly similar to your solution